# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \Delta?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $\Delta=\{(z,z): z\in \mathbb{C}\}$. What will be the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \Delta?$

I am unable to proceed at all. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Have you considered thinking of $\mathbb C^2$ as $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: Yeah, if I will take $\mathbb{C}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$ then the space is same as $\mathbb{R}\times (\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \mathbb{R})$. But then I don't know what to do.

Comment: $\Delta$ is the two-plane, with basis $(1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1)$. Now do a basis change...

Answer (score 2):

By using a linear transformation, we see that
$\Bbb C^2\setminus\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb C^2\setminus(\Bbb C
\times\{0\})$. This is homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$
which in turn is homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1$.

Comment: I am unable to get the Homotopy between $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\mathbb{C}\times \{0\})$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.